# How to convert a {200 VDC, 3A} power supply into a {12 VDC, 50A} source?

Tags: power-supply, dc, buck

As title states, want to convert a high-voltage, low-current DC bus to a low-voltage, high-current DC bus that's more compatible with electronics circuits. This seems to be a pretty large input for a buck DC/DC regulator?

Comment: Would you want to modify a unit? Not really in any meaningful way. Or build a converter to add onto it? Is there a reason you can't get a power supply of the desired rating instead?

Comment: Many off the shelf switched mode power supplies will accept dc input (as they simply rectify the normal AC input to DC).

Comment: This is absolutely a pretty large input, but it's not an insane input. My first thought was to look up Meanwell (a reputable brand) which has the part number SE-200-12, but unfortunately, although it is specified to work on AC or DC input, the DC input range is 254-370V, which is too high for you. (If you can rewire your solar panels to 300V 2A this part is ideal for you) If we pretend that this part is okay it would cost you about $70 and weight about 2kg (4.5 lbs). So, you know, it's not that crazy and you can buy the part off the shelf.

Comment: @Kartman - thanks! This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @user253751 - thanks, will lookup the part.

Comment: @necro well, it's not supposed to work on 200V DC input and I didn't find one that did. I just wanted to point out that your requirements aren't that large. Large for a hobbyist build, maybe; large for the professionals, absolutely not.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a high voltage low current source to a low voltage high current source, that’s done in pretty much any line powered low voltage supply, just with AC in instead of DC.

What you won’t be able to do is get 600 W out from 600 W in. That would take 100% efficiency and you won’t get near that. You’re probably looking at 40 A or less at 12 V and if you want to run mobile equipment from it you would want 13.8 V so even less current.